# Reduce Django serialization time

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am doing queries for roughly 100,000 rows with approximately 40 column each. The columns are of combination of float, integer, datetime, and char.

The query time is about two seconds, and serialization is taking forty seconds or more, whereas response building is about two seconds too.

I am wondering how can I reduce serialization time for Django models?

Here is my model:

```
class TelematicsData(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    analog_input_01 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    analog_input_02 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    analog_input_03 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    analog_input_04 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    analog_input_05 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    analog_input_06 = models.FloatField(null=True)

    device_temperature = models.FloatField(null=True)
    device_voltage = models.FloatField(null=True)
    vehicle_voltage = models.FloatField(null=True)

    absolute_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)
    brake_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)
    bump_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)
    turn_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)
    x_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)
    y_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)
    z_acceleration = models.FloatField(null=True)

    cell_location_error_meters = models.FloatField(null=True)
    engine_ignition_status = models.NullBooleanField()

    gnss_antenna_status = models.NullBooleanField()
    gnss_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='NA')
    gsm_signal_level = models.FloatField(null=True)
    gsm_sim_status = models.NullBooleanField()

    imei = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='NA')
    movement_status = models.NullBooleanField()
    peer = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='NA')

    position_altitude = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    position_direction = models.FloatField(null=True)
    position_hdop = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    position_latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    position_longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    position_point = models.PointField(null=True)
    position_satellites = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    position_speed = models.FloatField(null=True)
    position_valid = models.NullBooleanField()

    shock_event = models.NullBooleanField()
    hardware_version = models.FloatField(null=True)
    software_version = models.FloatField(null=True)

    record_sequence_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    timestamp_server = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    timestamp_unix = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    vehicle_mileage = models.FloatField(null=True)

    user_data_value_01 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    user_data_value_02 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    user_data_value_03 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    user_data_value_04 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    user_data_value_05 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    user_data_value_06 = models.FloatField(null=True)  
    user_data_value_07 = models.FloatField(null=True)  
    user_data_value_08 = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

and this is the serializer:

```
class TelematicsDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TelematicsData
        geo_field = ('position_point')
        #fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['id']
```

Comment: Do you need in one response the 100.000 objects or do it would be possible to paginate them?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For a different type of query, I did actually do with pagination.

Comment: Are you serializing foreign keys or another relations? Post your models and serializer, that would help.

Comment: At some point, you should drop the serializers for output and use Python's `json.dumps` likely with a custom JSONEncoder to deal with dates and other non json serializable types.

Comment: @grouchoboy I have edited my question to include my model.

Comment: Do you have access to the machine where this happens? Check memory (htop), I haven't done the calculation but holding the array of 100.000 objects in memory and processing it (probably copying each of them multiple times in a for-loop, keeping the serialised strings themselves in memory) might be the issue, causing a lot of swap on disk. Maybe increasing memory could be the simplest solution. Still, this won't scale indefinitely if your dataset increases.

Comment: @dirkgroten 

I have more than 8gb ram for this. The process doesnt even touch 10% of the memory used.

Comment: 40 seconds to serialize seems like a long time. Can you post your serializer code?

Comment: @WillKeeling I have updated the question to include the serializer.

Comment: Have you [profiled your code](https://julien.danjou.info/guide-to-python-profiling-cprofile-concrete-case-carbonara/) to determine whether the slowdown is actually in serialization of the data to JSON?

Comment: You need all data of model exclude `id` ? Get only field you want in serializer will reduce serialization time.

Comment: @hd1 yes I did that

Comment: @NgocPham Yes. All other fields are required.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post its output?

Comment: Is it possbile that querying the db is also part of those 40 seconds? Django does not evaluate querysets until they are used, so actual querying should take place after calling the method to serializer the data.

Comment: Another possbile cause could be the Device field in your model, I do not know how DRF works in that case, but if it is trying to fetch related Device objects even when only their id's would be used like in your case, that could be causing the problem as well. If that is the case, you can override get_queryset method to use prefetch_related in queryset to improve performance.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali as per my comment on the answer below, the device part does not affect much.

Comment: I see that you have relations in your model, have you tried creating a custom query using `prefetch_related(reverse_key_name)` and then serializing instead of using a ModelSerializer?

Comment: I can see a `geo_field` definition in your serializer.
Are you using a `rest_framework_gis.serializers.GeoFeatureModelSerializer` instead of a `rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer` ?

Comment: @AbhishekMenon Yes

Comment: @PaoloMelchiorre Yes

Comment: If you had eliminated all other possibilities, could you try using another serializer? https://github.com/clarkduvall/serpy (Serpy) is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In Short: Use Cache

IMHO, I don't think there is an issue with the serializer itself. But the problem is the size of data.

I have done some testing with serializer with 100K rows with your given model (without the POSTGIS part) and found that on average the Serialized data is generated in 18 seconds time in local machine. I tested django's default [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/), but it took around 20 seconds to get 100K rows.

A Side By Side comparison between **DRF Serializer** and **Django Serializer**:
[image: Side By Side Compraison]

So, as the **FK** relation is not very important and I also have tested with `prefetch_related`, it did not make much improvement either.

So, I would say, we need to improve elsewhere. IMHO, I think the bottleneck here is the DB. So you can do some improvements in there like [Index Caching](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25513/postgresql-index-caching) (FYI: I am not an expert in this, I don't know if its possible or not; by maybe worth a try).

But, there is a even a better approach is to use `in memory storage` to cache the data. You can use [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Storing/Retrieving 100K rows in **redis** also takes fairly less time then DB Query(about 2 seconds).
A screenshot from my local machine:

[image: Redis Store and Retrieve time]

You can try like this:

1. First, store the Json Data in Redis with a timeout. So after a certain time, the redis data will be erased and loaded from DB again.
2. When An API is called, first check if it exists in Redis, if it is, then serve from Redis
3. Else, serve from Seralizer and Store the JSON again in Redis.

Coding Example:

```
import json
import redis


class SomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        host = getattr(settings, "REDIS_HOST", 'localhost')  # assuming you have configuration in settings.py
        port = getattr(settings, "REDIS_PORT", 6379)
        KEY = getattr(settings, "REDIS_KEY", "TELE_DATA")
        TIME_OUT = getattr(settings, "REDIS_TIMEOUT", 3600)
        pool=redis.StrictRedis(host, port)
        data = pool.get(KEY)
        if not data:
             data = TelematicsDataSerializer(TelematicsData.objects.all(), many=True).data
             pool.set(KEY, json.dumps(data), e=TIME_OUT)
             return Response(data)
        else:
            return Response(json.loads(data))
```

There is two major downside of this solution.

1. The rows which are inserted between the timeout(lets say its one hour), then it will not be sent in the response
2. If the Redis is empty, then it will take 40+ seconds to send the response to user.

To overcome these problems, we can introduce something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), which will do periodic updates of the data in Redis. Meaning, we will define a new celery task, which will periodically load data in Redis and removing the older ones. We can try like this:

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/5')), name="load_cache", ignore_result=True)  # Runs every 5 minute
def load_cache():
    ...
    pool=redis.StrictRedis(host, port)
    json_data = TelematicsDataSerializer(TelematicsData.objects.all(), many=True).data
    pool.set(KEY, json.dumps(data))  # No need for timeout
```

And in the View:

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        host = getattr(settings, "REDIS_HOST", 'localhost')  # assuming you have configuration in settings.py
        port = getattr(settings, "REDIS_PORT", 6379)
        KEY = getattr(settings, "REDIS_KEY", "TELE_DATA")
        TIME_OUT = getattr(settings, "REDIS_TIMEOUT", 3600)
        pool=redis.StrictRedis(host, port)
        data = pool.get(KEY)
        return Response(json.loads(data))
```

So the user will be always receiving data from cache. There is also a downside for this solution, the data user will get might not have the latest rows(if they are in-between the interval time of the celery task). But lets say you want to force celery to reload the cache using `load_cache.apply_async()`(to run asynchronously) or `load_cache.apply()`(run synchronously).

Also, you can use many alternatives to Redis for caching, like `memcache`, `elastic search` etc.

---

### Experimental:

As the data size is huge, maybe you can compress the data when storing and decompress it when loading. But it will reduce the performance, not sure by what margin. You can try like this:

#### Compression

```
import pickle
import gzip

....

binary_data = pickle.dumps(data)
compressed_data = gzip.compress(binary_data)
pool.set(KEY, compressed_data)  # No need to use JSON Dumps
```

#### Decompression

```
import pickle
import gzip

....

compressed_data = pool.get(KEY)
binary_data = gzip.decompress(compressed_data)
data = pickle.loads(binary_data)
```

Comment: Thanks @ruddra but we are talking about the whole database here and if putting on redis, it really would take some a lot in memory database...

Comment: @AfeezAziz Um, you can use some compression as well. I have given one example in experimental section, but I can't assure how much performance will hamper or will it even work. But I hope it will give you some idea on how you can do it properly.

Comment: @AfeezAziz another thing is that, you can put chunks of your data in Redis instead of whole DB. maybe the first 20K rows can be put into the redis. It will not reduce performance or will create memory crisis.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "device" is the key issue here, if it is not joined correctly it will query the database for every record you have. As a test, you can add "device" to the exclude list to see if the performance improves.

Comment: No, device is not the reason. Total query time is just 2 seconds. I added device to the exclude list, the performance does not improve much.